# Shell script to prompt yes or no while going though install

Tags: linux, bash, shell, prompt

I'm trying to create a shell script that prompts a set of questions and based on the answer it runs a command. If at anytime "*no*" is entered then the shell script exits. For example:

1. Do you want to install the new update yes or no?
   if user inputs yes then run following script (*./install.sh*)
2. What is the current date?  Or a previous date that matches a *rundate.sh* file.  If user inputs "*201707*" then run (*./rundate201707.sh*)
3. Would you like to run the patch? yes or no?
   if user inputs "*yes*" then run *./patch.sh*

Any advice would be greatly appreciated.

EDIT: Adding code. My real issue is adding the date to the end of the shell script when entered.

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    read -p "do you want to install the new update?[Y/n]: " yn
    case $yn in
        [Yy]* ) ./install.sh; break;;
        [Nn]* ) break;;
        * ) echo "Please answer yes or no.";;
    esac
done
while true; do
    echo -n "Enter the date as YYYYMMDD:> " 
      read date
      if [ ${#date} -eq 8 ]; then
```

Comment: Start with google: [Shell script to prompt yes or no](https://www.google.com/search?q=Shell+script+to+prompt+yes+or+no).  SO works best, as @mklement0 says, when you have specific code with a specific problem.

Comment: thanks @John1024 and mklement0 I added the code. I should have mentioned this before. My real issue is at the second prompt where the user is asked to enter the date and what ever is entered get's attached to the end of "run date" script

Answer (score 2):

Using a function that exploits the `bash` version of `read`'s `-sN1` switches, (`-sN1` prints nothing, and only reads 1 character):

```
yn() { echo -n "$1: "
       while read  -sN1 x ; do 
           x=${x,}
           case $x in [yn]) break ;; *) : ;; esac
       done
       echo $x
       [ $x = y ] ; }

yn "Do you want to install the new update? [Y/n]" || exit
./install.sh
echo "Pick a rundate file: "
select x in ./rundate????????.sh ; do $x ; break ; done
yn "Would you like to run the patch? [Y/n]" || exit
./patch.sh
```

Notes:

1. Converting `$x` to lower case with `x=${x,}` simplifies the testing.
2. `yn` doesn't respond to anything *but* `[yYnN]`, so there's no need for a reminder prompt.
3. `yn` returns a *true/false* exit code which simplifies the testing.
4. The `select` command returns the *rundate* file name, then runs it.

Comment: Thanks @agc ! The only reason I want the user to be promoted for the date is because they can chose a previous date to be added to the script name. It's not always  going to be the current date

Comment: @connollyc4, Re "*choose a previous date*":  Assuming there's not too many such file, a `select` statement should work.  See new code in answer.